# Closing EXCEL using batch job

Tags: excel, batch-file

I have a batch job that creates some CSV files, which I import into EXCEL using macros. I then use the batch job to open the EXCEL file, using the "start" command. However, I do not want to incorporate the closing from within EXCEL, as I want this batch job to open and close the EXCEL file, not a macro. The point will be that I will populate the EXCEL file, but another person needs to open this file and examine the results, so I cannot have a macro that closes it automatically. Any help would be great!

Comment: I am working on an MS server 2003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there is not way to actually save automated macro changes and then close excel, without using VBA. However, in my case, the data is still available, so terminating the excel.exe is enough, since the excel will run the macros when it is opened and the user/s can save the work then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  **taskkill /f /im excel.exe > nul** to close the open Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
taskkill /IM excel.exe
```

Comment: I actually tried this, and it doesn't work. You don't think it has anything to do with the fact that I am using the "timeout" command?

Comment: no, it was not working because I was trying to copy the file first. However, the problem now is that it closes excel, but the macro made changes that were not saved. Any idea if this can be done from the dos command?

Comment: How do you call the Macros from the batch file?

Comment: actually I simply start the EXCEL from the batch file, i.e. start excelFile.exe, which already has macros that run when the workbook is opened. I added activeworkbook.save to see if the workbook would be saved, but it isn't. Therefore, when I KILL excel, I loose the macros' changes.

Comment: so you have the macros in the Workbook_Open event?

Comment: actually, each macro imports data into a tab (separately) and within is sub-routine, I say activeworkbook.save. I do not have a workbook_open, because I am opening the workbook from the batch job.

Comment: We are starting to get beyond the scope of your initial question. To keep the integrity of the site, you'll probably need to open another question and we can move the discussion there.